# Masking of 2 UIImages in Retina Quality

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, retina-display, mask

After trying the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776747/masking-a-uiimage) the image that gets returned is of a very poor quality on the retina display. My mask image has a white background and black contents.

Output: https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/22373o2Z260d3S051a05/Screenshot%202013.01.02%2000.04.57.png?v=34c4ab14

Code:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 61.0f, 53.0f);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 2);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

UIImage *imageGradient = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImage *toggleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RotationToggle.png"];
UIImage *inputImage = imageGradient;
CGImageRef maskRef = toggleImage.CGImage;

CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(imageGradient.CGImage, mask);
CGImageRelease(mask);

UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked scale:inputImage.scale orientation:0];
CGImageRelease(masked);
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not completely sure, but try changing this line:

```
UIImage *toggleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RotationToggle.png"];
```

to this:

```
UIImage *toggleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RotationToggle"];
```

or naive this:

```
UIImage *toggleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RotationToggle@2x.png"];
```

The thing is: I think you force it to use low-quality image by assigning it this way. When skipping extension, Xcode will automatically look for Retina image and assign it if there exists one.

I may be wrong though, sorry if so.